# How to redirect incoming traffic to a different port, on a Synology NAS (DSM5)

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, synology

Should be simple using `iptables`, as for example [described in this post by Richard Fergie](http://richardfergie.com/redirect-port-80-to-a-different-port-using-iptables), but my device, a Synology DS115j (Running DSM 5.0) is not able to do so apparently:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

returns

```
iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

**Do I need to use the `nat` table at all for port forwarding?** This is no gateway and do not want to forward to another device, only to another local port.

Context:

- My goal is to run a server on a non-privileged port to avoid having to run it as root.
- I know about `setcap` and `authbind` but these are not available on a Synology NAS (DSM5).
- Synology DS115j also does not support [Docker](https://www.synology.com/en-us/dsm/app_packages/Docker).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the synology firewall does not already use nat then the necessary kernel modules will probably not be enabled, so `-t nat` will not find the table. You need to, as root:

```
cd /lib/modules
insmod nf_nat.ko 
insmod iptable_nat.ko
insmod ipt_REDIRECT.ko
```

Then `iptables -L -t nat` should list the empty chains, `lsmod|grep nat` should show the modules, and you can add your rule.

Comment: This worked excellent on my Synology DS115j NAS.

Answer (score 1):

The Synology Os (DSM) uses a closed source binary called `firewalltool` to rebuild the iptables dump. You could invest time to understand how it works internally by looking at `/usr/syno/etc/rc.d/S01iptables.sh` and `/etc/firewall`, but keep in mind that any DSM update may overwrite manual changes you made.

Comment: I looked into the .sh script a bit and I am terrified to mingle with that. Also, besides getting overwritten at update, it breaks the Admin GUI firewall feature, AFAIK.

Comment: In any case, when I try this kind of things I normally do it via containers, which keep everything "contained", without populating the DSM. Check if your model supports virtualization (docker) https://www.synology.com/en-us/dsm/app_packages/Docker

Comment: Good Idea. Unfortunately, it also does not support Docker. I looked it up, and updated the question.